# Kubernetes replace deployment fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes

I have created a NodeJS script for deploying review apps to Kubernetes for my GitLab repository. To
do this, I’m using the Kubernetes NodeJS client.

For completeness sake, I have included truncated definitions of the Kubernetes resources.

```js
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const logger = require('../logger');

const {
  CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME,
  CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
  CI_ENVIRONMENT_URL,
  CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE,
  KUBE_NAMESPACE,
} = process.env;

const { hostname } = new URL(CI_ENVIRONMENT_URL);

const mysqlDeployment = {
  apiVersion: 'apps/v1',
  kind: 'Deployment',
  metadata: {
    name: `${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-mysql`,
    labels: {
      app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
      tier: 'mysql',
    },
  },
  spec: {
    replicas: 1,
    selector: {
      matchLabels: {
        app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
        tier: 'mysql',
      },
    },
    template: {
      metadata: {
        labels: {
          app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
          tier: 'mysql',
        },
      },
      spec: {
        containers: [
          {
            image: 'mysql:8',
            name: 'mysql',
          },
        ],
        ports: { containerPort: 3306 },
      },
    },
  },
};

const mysqlService = {
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  kind: 'Service',
  metadata: {
    name: `${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-mysql`,
    labels: {
      app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
      tier: 'mysql',
    },
  },
  spec: {
    ports: [{ port: 3306 }],
    selector: {
      app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
      tier: 'mysql',
    },
    clusterIP: 'None',
  },
};

const appDeployment = {
  apiVersion: 'apps/v1',
  kind: 'Deployment',
  metadata: {
    name: `${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-frontend`,
    labels: {
      app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
      tier: 'frontend',
    },
  },
  spec: {
    replicas: 1,
    selector: {
      matchLabels: {
        app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
        tier: 'frontend',
      },
    },
    template: {
      metadata: {
        labels: {
          app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
          tier: 'frontend',
        },
      },
      spec: {
        containers: [
          {
            image: `${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}`,
            imagePullPolicy: 'Always',
            name: 'app',
            ports: [{ containerPort: 9999 }],
          },
        ],
        imagePullSecrets: [{ name: 'registry.gitlab.com' }],
      },
    },
  },
};

const appService = {
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  kind: 'Service',
  metadata: {
    name: `${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-frontend`,
    labels: {
      app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
      tier: 'frontend',
    },
  },
  spec: {
    ports: [{ port: 9999 }],
    selector: {
      app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
      tier: 'frontend',
    },
    clusterIP: 'None',
  },
};

const ingress = {
  apiVersion: 'extensions/v1beta1',
  kind: 'Ingress',
  metadata: {
    name: `${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-ingress`,
    labels: {
      app: CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG,
    },
    annotations: {
      'certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer': 'letsencrypt-prod',
      'kubernetes.io/ingress.class': 'nginx',
      'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size': '50m',
    },
  },
  spec: {
    tls: [
      {
        hosts: [hostname],
        secretName: `${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-prod`,
      },
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        host: hostname,
        http: {
          paths: [
            {
              path: '/',
              backend: {
                serviceName: `${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}-frontend`,
                servicePort: 9999,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I use the following functions to deploy these resources to Kubernetes.

```js
async function noConflict(resource, create, replace) {
  const { kind } = resource;
  const { name } = resource.metadata;
  try {
    logger.info(`Creating ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
    await create(KUBE_NAMESPACE, resource);
    logger.info(`Created ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response.statusCode !== 409) {
      throw err;
    }
    logger.warn(`${kind} ${name} already exists… Replacing instead.`);
    await replace(name, KUBE_NAMESPACE, resource);
    logger.info(`Replaced ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
  }
}

async function deploy() {
  const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
  kc.loadFromDefault();
  const apps = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.Apps_v1Api);
  const beta = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.Extensions_v1beta1Api);
  const core = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.Core_v1Api);

  await noConflict(
    mysqlDeployment,
    apps.createNamespacedDeployment.bind(apps),
    apps.replaceNamespacedDeployment.bind(apps),
  );
  await noConflict(
    mysqlService,
    core.createNamespacedService.bind(core),
    core.replaceNamespacedService.bind(core),
  );
  await noConflict(
    appDeployment,
    apps.createNamespacedDeployment.bind(apps),
    apps.replaceNamespacedDeployment.bind(apps),
  );
  await noConflict(
    appService,
    core.createNamespacedService.bind(core),
    core.replaceNamespacedService.bind(core),
  );
  await noConflict(
    ingress,
    beta.createNamespacedIngress.bind(beta),
    beta.replaceNamespacedIngress.bind(beta),
  );
}
```

The initial deployment goes fine, but the replacement of the mysql service fails with the following
HTTP request body.

```js
{ kind: 'Status',
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  metadata: {},
  status: 'Failure',
  message:
   'Service "review-fix-kubern-8a4yh2-mysql" is invalid: metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: "": must be specified for an update',
  reason: 'Invalid',
  details:
   { name: 'review-fix-kubern-8a4yh2-mysql',
     kind: 'Service',
     causes: [Array] },
  code: 422 } }
```

I have tried modifying `noConflict` to get the current version, and use the active `versionResource`
to replace resources.

```js
async function noConflict(resource, create, get, replace) {
  const { kind, metadata } = resource;
  const { name } = resource.metadata;
  try {
    logger.info(`Creating ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
    await create(KUBE_NAMESPACE, resource);
    logger.info(`Created ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response.statusCode !== 409) {
      throw err;
    }
    logger.warn(`${kind} ${name} already exists… Replacing instead.`);
    const {
      body: {
        metadata: { resourceVersion },
      },
    } = await get(name, KUBE_NAMESPACE);
    const body = {
      ...resource,
      metadata: {
        ...metadata,
        resourceVersion,
      },
    };
    logger.warn(`${kind} ${name} already exists… Replacing instead.`);
    await replace(name, KUBE_NAMESPACE, body);
    logger.info(`Replaced ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
  }
}
```

However, this gives me another error.

```js
{ kind: 'Status',
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  metadata: {},
  status: 'Failure',
  message:
   'Service "review-prevent-ku-md2ghh-frontend" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable',
  reason: 'Invalid',
  details:
   { name: 'review-prevent-ku-md2ghh-frontend',
     kind: 'Service',
     causes: [Array] },
  code: 422 } }
```

What should I do to replace the running resources?

Whether or not the the database stays up, is a minor detail.

**Update**

To address the comment by LouisBaumann:

I have changed by code to the following, where `read` is the respective read call for each resource.

```
async function noConflict(resource, create, read, replace) {
  const { kind } = resource;
  const { name } = resource.metadata;
  try {
    logger.info(`Creating ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
    await create(KUBE_NAMESPACE, resource);
    logger.info(`Created ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response.statusCode !== 409) {
      throw err;
    }
    logger.warn(`${kind} ${name} already exists… Replacing instead.`);
    const { body: existing } = await read(name, KUBE_NAMESPACE);
    await replace(name, KUBE_NAMESPACE, merge(existing, resource));
    logger.info(`Replaced ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
  }
}
```

The above doesn’t crash, but it doesn’t update the review environment either.

**Update**

To address the answer by Crou:

I have updated the replace calls with patch calls. So the `noConflict` function becomes:

```
async function noConflict(resource, create, patch) {
  const { kind } = resource;
  const { name } = resource.metadata;
  try {
    logger.info(`Creating ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
    await create(KUBE_NAMESPACE, resource);
    logger.info(`Created ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response.statusCode !== 409) {
      throw err;
    }
    logger.warn(`${kind} ${name} already exists… Patching instead.`);
    await patch(name, KUBE_NAMESPACE, resource);
    logger.info(`Replaced ${kind.toLowerCase()}: ${name}`);
  }
}
```

I also changed the `noConflict` calls to pass the patch versions instead of the replace functions.

```
await noConflict(
  mysqlDeployment,
  apps.createNamespacedDeployment.bind(apps),
  apps.patchNamespacedDeployment.bind(apps),
);
// etc
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "415: Unsupported Media Type",
  "reason": "UnsupportedMediaType",
  "details": {},
  "code": 415
}
```

Comment: Are you able to read the already existing object from the k8s api? I resolved this by reading the existing object and then just edit the properties i wanted to change.

Comment: In practive, this makes the replace call look like this: `const { body: existing } = await read(name, KUBE_NAMESPACE); await replace(name, KUBE_NAMESPACE, lodash.merge(existing, resource));`. This didn’t crash, but it doesn’t update the running review environment either.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are using [`replace`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#replace) incorrectly.

> Replace a resource by filename or stdin.
>
> JSON and YAML formats are accepted. If replacing an existing resource, the complete resource spec must be provided. This can be obtained by
>
> `$ kubectl get TYPE NAME -o yaml`

If you do replace without getting the `yaml` from Kubernetes, you are missing `resourceVersion`. So this is why you get the error:

`Service "review-fix-kubern-8a4yh2-mysql" is invalid: metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: "": must be specified for an update`

You should use [`patch`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch) or [`apply`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply) if you are replacing just parts of the `Deployment`.

Comment: This returned: `{ "kind": "Status", "apiVersion": "v1", "metadata": {}, "status": "Failure", "message": "415: Unsupported Media Type", "reason": "UnsupportedMediaType", "details": {}, "code": 415 }`

Comment: You need to provide more details what exactly is being changed to what.

Comment: You’re right. I tried to respond in a comment, but that didn’t suffice. I updated the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trough the same issue as you today, what i wanted to mimic using the node client was the `kubectl apply -f` command luckily i found a typescript snippet [here](http://I%27ve%20been%20trough%20the%20same%20issue%20as%20you%20today,%20what%20i%20wanted%20to%20mimic%20using%20the%20node%20client%20was%20the%20%60kubectl%20apply%20-f%60%20command%20luckily%20i%20found%20a%20typescript%20snippet%20here%20%60https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/typescript/apply/apply-example.ts%60.%20Hope%20it%20helps%20out.). Hope it helps out!.

So i end up using in javascript

```
const kubernetesConfig = new k8s.KubeConfig()
kubernetesConfig.loadFromFile("kube-config.yaml")
this.k8sClient = k8s.KubernetesObjectApi.makeApiClient(kubernetesConfig)
```

and created an `apply function`

```
 async apply(spec) {
  try {
    // try to get the resource, if it does not exist an error will be thrown and we will end up in the catch
    // block.
    await this.k8sClient.read(spec)
    // we got the resource, so it exists, so patch it
    await this.k8sClient.patch(spec)
  } catch (e) {
    // we did not get the resource, so it does not exist, so create it
    await this.k8sClient.create(spec)
  }
},
```